# How to hold values in variable in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I need to fetch max length of First_name and put it into @sq i am getting an error.

```
Declare @sq nvarchar(max) 
Set @sq=''

SELECT MAX(LEN(FIRST_NAME))  FROM #table1
Drop table #t

SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(SEQ_NUM) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE SEQ_NUM END AS REC_NUM,
    CASE WHEN LEN(FIRST_NAME) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE CONVERT(CHAR(Select @sq)),RTRIM(UPPER(FIRST_NAME))) END AS FIRST_NAME
into #t
from #tabel1
```

Comment: And that error is...?

Comment: Described in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/variables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), in the [Setting a Value in a Transact-SQL Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/variables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#setting-a-value-in-a-transact-sql-variable) paragraph. Use `SELECT @sq=MAX(...)`

Comment: On the other hand, you don't need that variable at all. Use `SELECT MAX(LEN(FIRST_NAME))  FROM #table1` as a subquery in the second query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the variable, like this:

```
Declare @sq int  --LEN returns an int, not a varchar!

SELECT @sq = MAX(LEN(FIRST_NAME))
FROM #table1
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a few problem with this SQL. If we start with the first statement:

```
Set @sq=''SELECT MAX(LEN(FIRST_NAME))  FROM #table1
```

You have a couple of wayward single quotes here (`'`); not sure what they're doing. Secondly, if you're assigning a variables value from a dataset, the syntax is `SELECT {Variable} = {expression} [,{Variable} = {expression} [,...]] FROM {etc}` Thus you get:

```
SELECT @sq = MAX(LEN(FIRST_NAME))
FROM #table1;
```

The next statement, well, that's a mess. Firstly, there's also a wayward right parenthesis (`)`) here: `RTRIM(UPPER(FIRST_NAME)))` There should only be 2.

The expression `CONVERT(CHAR(Select @sq))` is very wrong. `CONVERT` require 2 parameters, but only has one, and `CHAR` would return an character for the appropriate number provided. I.e. `CHAR(65)` returns `A`. I *suspect* you mean `CONVERT(char,@sq)` (you should really be declaring a length here!), however, `@sq` is already an `nvarchar(max)` (which is also pointless, as it's being assigned the value of an `int`). Thus I literally have no idea what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion... i need to declare a length in case condition i CONVERT(CHAR(SELECT @sq)-- need output as convert(char(17) that is max of len of firstname