# How to declare length in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I need to declare max of length in case condition i.e 7 but getting error incorrect syntax near select

```
DECLARE @SQ Int(MAX) 
SELECT @SQ= MAX(LEN(FIRST_NAME))  FROM #table
SELECT @SQ 
-- 7

DROP TABLE #T
SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(SEQ_NUM) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE SEQ_NUM END AS REC_NUM,
CASE WHEN LEN(FIRST_NAME) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE CONVERT(CHAR(SELECT @SQ= MAX(LEN(FIRST_NAME)) 
 FROM #table),RTRIM(UPPER(FIRST_NAME))) END AS FIRST_NAME
 INTO #T
FROM #table

--== Need  7 Char(7) -- Max of len
DROP TABLE #T
SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(SEQ_NUM) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE SEQ_NUM END AS REC_NUM,
CASE WHEN LEN(FIRST_NAME) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE CONVERT(CHAR(7),RTRIM(UPPER(FIRST_NAME))) END AS FIRST_NAME
 INTO #T
FROM #table
```

Comment: `CONVERT(CHAR(SELECT @SQ= MAX(LEN(FIRST_NAME))`. That's an even worse format that it was before (you're mixing variable assigningment in the middle of a `SELECT` statement, while trying to use `CONVERT` with one parameter, and use the [`CHAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/char-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) functio). I explained why this doesn't work in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52888456/how-to-hold-values-in-variable-in-sql-server/52888609#52888609) to your other question. I've no idea what you're trying to achieve there though.

Comment: Correction, you *are* passing 2 parameter to `CONVERT`. The first parameter is `CHAR(SELECT @SQ= MAX(LEN(FIRST_NAME)) 
 FROM #table)`; the first parameter should be a datatype. The second parameter is `RTRIM(UPPER(FIRST_NAME))`. Not sure what you're trying that value to, as it is clearly already a string of some kind.

Comment: You don't need to specify the length of the integer.
Instead of `DECLARE @SQ Int(MAX) ` change it to `DECLARE @SQ Int`
Let me know if that works?

Comment: If you are using sql server AND that is actually the code you are running that is not the error message you are getting. The INT datatype does not have size, you would get error 2716